# How to test if the Couchbase process is running in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, process

I have installed Couchbase Server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop. I'm new to Linux and have watched tutorials and done beginners research. However after installing Couchbase NoSQL, I can open the admin panel in firefox with localhost:8091 so I know it is running, I have two questions:

1. After shutting down the Ubuntu machine and restarting it, Couchbase
   has started, so where is the entry to start Couchbase or indeed and
   script/program?
2. I'm aware of `ps`, `ps aux` and `pgrep` commands to check for running
   processes but I can't see the `couchbase` service. Where is it?

Comment: You can telnet the server port `telnet localhost {port_numbre}`

Comment: do you mind telling why you want to know this?

Comment: @Mark Yisri Yes my brain works bottom up, I need to know why things work the way they do, takes me ages doing stuff but its worth it. Also I think its fundamental knowing how to check your processes to keep an eye on things. Great community here BTW.

Comment: For completeness: the ongoing Couchbase process is called beam.smp and the process id's can be seen if you use 'pgrep beam.smp'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Couchbase documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/install/linux-startup-shutdown.html) it is apparent that the service starts as part of init scripts in `/etc/init.d/`. That means you should be able to find your service via `service --status-all` or if you're on Ubuntu 16.04 and newer via  `systemctl list-units --type=service` command.

Comment: Thank you @Serg init.d and --status added to my knowledge base.